# Find value indexes in a mother array with a filter array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have two arrays: one is a mother array and the other is a "filtering array". The mother array is a 2D array (about 65 rowsx147 cols in size). The filtering array is an array that has the max value of each column of the mother array (1 row x 147 cols). I need to get the matching row values for the max values.

I tried using

```
for index,k in np.ndenumerate(MotherArr):
    for val in FiltArr:
        if k == val:
            print(index)
```

But for some reason, I am basically getting a print of val with the very last index printed afterwards.

Any ideas on how I could get this working?

Answer (score 0):

You can just take the [`argmax`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.argmax.html) of your array along an axis:

```
np.random.seed(0)
A = np.random.randint(0, 10, (5, 5))

# array([[5, 0, 3, 3, 7],
#        [9, 3, 5, 2, 4],
#        [7, 6, 8, 8, 1],
#        [6, 7, 7, 8, 1],
#        [5, 9, 8, 9, 4]])

maxima = A.max(1)
# array([7, 9, 8, 8, 9])

maxima_args = A.argmax(1)
# array([4, 0, 2, 3, 1], dtype=int64)
```

Comment: How would this be altered to get the column index values as well as the row index values? When you use argmax you only get one or the other, depending on what axis you do it on. I am trying to get the maxes of the columns, but get their 2D index in the mother wavelet.

Comment: The row index is simply `np.arange(A.shape[0])`. What's the **precise** format you are looking for?